# pasar array de strings PHP a array de objetos (JSON) en javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Básicamente quiero mostrar unos datos de mi base de datos y para ello necesito pasarlos por php, pero luego necesito convertirlos en esto:

```
var consumptions2 = {

            '14' : ['ejemplo', 50, 23.00, 1, 'red', 'list-red'],
            'consumption3' : ['dijey evans', 420, 1000, 1, 'green', 'list-green'],
            'consumption4' : ['Weight Loss Shake', 10, 1.05, 1, '', ''],
            'consumption5' : ['Pure Protein', 10, 1.35, 1, 'white', 'list-white'],
            'consumption6' : ['Health Shake', 10, 1.05, 1, 'darkgreen', 'list-darkgreen'],
            'consumption7' : ['Clear &amp; Refreshing', 10, 1.05, 1, '', ''],
            'consumption8' : ['Shot of Health', 10, 1.05, 1, 'blue', 'list-blue'],
            'consumption9' : ['Chocolate Delight', 10, 1.05, 1, '', ''],
            'consumption10' : ['Strawberry Shortcake', 10, 1.05, 1, 'red', 'list-red'],
            'consumption11' : ['Berry Mix', 10, 1.05, 1, 'white', 'list-white'],
            'consumption12' : ['Crazy Shake', 10, 1.05, 1, '', ''],
            'consumption18' : ['6 Pack', 25, 20.11, 1, 'blue', 'list-blue'],
            'consumption19' : ['12 Pack', 100, 37.15, 1, '', ''],
            'consumption20' : ['24 Pack', 250, 100.25, 1, '', ''],
            'consumption20' : ['34 pack', 250, 100.25, 1, '', '']
        };
```

Entonces, desde PHP haciendo esto:

```
    <?php 
    require_once("conexion.php");
    //select
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM productos";
    $sql2 = "SELECT nombre FROM productos";
    
         
             
    
    //CONTADOR PARA LAS COMAS****
           if (!$resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql2)) {
                die("Error en select");
               }
    
        $contAux = 0;
        while($fila = $resultado2->fetch_assoc()){
            
            $contAux++;
        }      
    //CONTADOR PARA LAS COMAS****
    
    
        
    
    if (!$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
      

      die("Error en select");
       }
        
        $datos = "{";
    
        $cont=0;
        while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            
            $datos.="'".$fila["idProducto"]."' : ['".$fila["nombre"]."', ".$fila["precio"].", 23.00, 1, 'red', 'list-red']";

            
            if($cont<$contAux-1) {
                $datos.=",";
            }
            $cont++;
        }
        $datos.="};";

        echo $datos;
?>
```

Conseguí que me mostrara esto, que la sintaxis es practicamente igual a la de la variable en JS:

```
{'17' : ['doritos', 4.20, 23.00, 1, 'red', 'list-red'],'19' : ['dew', 1.21, 23.00, 1, 'red', 'list-red'],'31' : ['pepino', 70.00, 23.00, 1, 'red', 'list-red'],'34' : ['verde', 12.90, 23.00, 1, 'red', 'list-red'],'36' : ['spaghettis', 9.99, 23.00, 1, 'red', 'list-red'],'37' : ['azul', 0.00, 23.00, 1, 'red', 'list-red'],'41' : ['patatas', 90.00, 23.00, 1, 'red', 'list-red']};
```

El problema es que lo coge como un array de tipo String, y obviamente lo que necesito es uno de tipo objeto, lo he intentado parsear de varias maneras y nada, alguna ayuda?

Comment: No te vendría mejor utilizar json_encode después de haber creado un array normal de los datos de tu consulta a la BBDD?

Comment: No te vendría mejor utilizar json_encode después de haber creado un array normal de los datos de tu consulta a la BBDD?

Comment: Como bien dice @Jakala, si quieres un JSON en respuesta, usa `json_encode` desde el servidor. En el cliente, si estás usando Ajax y ya pusiste un `dataType: 'json'` no necesitas siquiera hacer parse, el mismo se hace solo. En cuanto a la estructura misma de tu JSON, me parece poco práctica para una lectura automática. Es mejor crear un array de consumptions, sin nombrado de claves del tipo `consumption1, consumption2, consumptionN`, los arrays existen para algo, si metes todo en un array podrás leer los valores en un bucle, haya un elemento, haya `N` elementos.

Comment: @Jakala he intentado usar el json_encode  pero el problema esque lo sigue cogiendo todo como un string en vez de un objeto

Comment: Pero eso es precisamente lo que quieres. Una cadena Json. La cosa entonces cuando lo envies de vuelta a JavaScript, debe llegar con las cabeceras de Json, y que tú cavascript lo interprete...

Comment: @Jakala al final usé ajax y dividí el string con la funcion split() para convertirlo en array y ya me funciona, seguramente no sea muy buena practica hacer  lo que he hecho, pero bueno

Comment: muchas gracias a todos